# How can I split my normalization in two according to column values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, normalization, distribution

HI I have a column data in pandas with a hugely skewed distribution:
[image: data distribution]

I split the data in two according to a cutoff value of 1000 and this is the distribution of the two groups. 
[image]

Now, I want to normalize with values between 0-1. I want to perform a 'differential' normalization, in a way that the left panel values are normalized between 0-0.5 and the right panel is normalized to 0.5 to 1, everything in the same column. How can I do it?

Comment: Just to be sure, since splitting a histogram plot is very unusual: Do you have a specific reason to take this approach or do you just want to visualize this distribution properly? If you want the latter, try to plot it as log (`plt.semilogy`) or double log (`plt.loglog`)

Comment: It is not visualization, the reason is that I'm trying to convert this in an image, taking this to the 0-255 range. I want low and high values to contribute to the image more or less to the same extent.

Comment: Putting words in quotes does not magically make clear the idiosyncratic specific meaning that you didn't write out.

Comment: @philipxy ok, clear for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dataExample': [0,1,2,1001,1002,1003]})

less1000 = df.loc[df['dataExample'] <= 1000]
df.loc[df['dataExample'] <= 1000, 'datanorm'] =  less1000['dataExample'] / (less1000['dataExample'].max() * 2)

high1000 = df.loc[df['dataExample'] > 1000]
df.loc[df['dataExample'] > 1000, 'datanorm'] =  ((high1000['dataExample'] - high1000['dataExample'].min()) / ((high1000['dataExample'].max() - high1000['dataExample'].min()) * 2) + 0.5)

output:
    dataExample datanorm
0   0   0.00
1   1   0.25
2   2   0.50
3   1001    0.50
4   1002    0.75
5   1003    1.00
```

Comment: thanks, close to... normalization is ok, but I should get one column with all values, and got two. I need two norms conditional to <>1000, all in same column.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your dataframe is called `df`, the column holding the data is called `data` and the column holding the counts is called `counts`. Then you could do something like this:

```
df['data_norm'] = df['data'].loc[df['counts']<=1000] / 1000 / 2
df['data_norm'] = df['data'].loc[df['counts']>1000] / df['counts'].max() + 0.5
```

... assuming I understood you correctly. But I think I neither understand your problem properly nor your approach to solve it.